# How to create a window instance with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a 'helper' object in a file called 'helper.js'

```
helper = {};
helper.hello = function(name) {
    return 'hello' + name;
};
helper.bye = function(name) {
    return 'bye' + name;
};
```

How can I make a window instance of this object so that my 'helper.js' could be visible to others js files?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want a global variable? That code right there will do it for you; just load it in your page before the rest of your code. [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EczGz8nYGgpMoxOsvvMy?p=preview)

Comment: The code I'm working on is using module pattern, sometimes the global variable is not read due to the encapsulation code.

Comment: Then attach it to the window, as Ray said. `window.helper = helper`.

Comment: @MikeC, yes thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
helper = {};
helper.hello = function(name) {
    return 'hello' + name;
};
helper.bye = function(name) {
    return 'bye' + name;
};
window.helper=helper ;
```

Comment: is this what u r expecting to access this to in all files?